# Determine if Silverlight CAN be installed

Tags: javascript, silverlight

I am developing a page that needs to work in a variety of scenarios that is determined using JavaScript.  Firstly if Silverlight is installed it should use Silverlight.  Simple.

```
if(Silverlight.isInstalled()){
    // do stuff
}
```

Next I need to be able to determine if Silverlight CAN be installed.  This is the hard bit.  Basically if I am viewing the on, say for example, an iPad (but could be any non-Silverlight capable device) I want to use plain HTML.  But if I am on a desktop machine that doesn't have Silverlight installed but can install it I wan't the usual install Silverlight stuff

```
Silverlight.getSilverlight();
```

I have seen the [Silverlight.supportedUserAgent.js](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/SLsupportedUA) but like most UA sniffing techniques is a bit backwards.  Is there a way feature detect such a thing?

Comment: Hopefully they don't have JS disabled. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not entirely sure this is possible using feature detection.  Not reliably anyway.  I have decided to use the above Silverlight.supportedUserAgent.js library instead.